# Casting an array to NgIterable<T> in Angular 4+ (ngForOf)

Tags: angular, angular5, directive, ngfor

I am trying to modify the directive `ngForOf` directive. The directive should procure the iterable object by its own. How do i have to cast an `Array` to get an object of type `NgIterable<T>` ?

```
// original
// @Input() ngForOf: NgIterable<T>; 


// modified
ngForOf:any;

constructor(...){
this.ngForOf = [1,2,3] // Example Array
}
```

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NgIterable](https://angular.io/api/core/NgIterable) is a type alias of `Array` an `Iterable` so you don't have to cast.

The problem here is ngForOf is NgIterable where T is not defined (at least in the code we can see) try:

```
@Input() ngForOf: NgIterable<number>;

constructor(...){
  this.ngForOf = [1,2,3] // Example Array
}
```

So in your case you want to use generic you will need to do some thing like

```
import { Input, NgIterable } from '@angular/core';

export class MyForOf<T> {
  @Input() ngForOf: NgIterable<T> = [];
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. Is there a way i can use 
<my-component *ngFor></my-component> instead of <my-component *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3]"></my-component> because the modified directive needs no @Input(), but does'nt work without

Comment: You should ask another question because a lot of  code is missing to help you.